# Cambiar prioridad de procesos en linux

Tags: linux, proceso

Como cambiar la prioridad de un proceso, sin tener que reiniciarlo,  o sea sin usar renice.

Comment: De dónde sale la premisa que `renice` es reiniciarlo????

Answer (score -1):

Teniendo el `PID` del proceso en ejecución, uno ajusta el *niceness* del proceso, que es el nivel de cheveridad de dicho proceso para con los demás. Cheveridad entendida como proclividad a dejar que los demás agarren tiempo de CPU.

Así pues, usar `renice -N pid`, con un número negativo para la cheveridad, hace que el proceso no ceda y tenga prioridad por sobre otros.

Ejemplo

`renice -20 20222` hace que el proceso con PID 20222 sea mucho menos chévere que procesos con *nice number* positivo o cero. Entre más negativo, menos chévere es y menos cede tiempo de CPU para el *process scheduler* (la parte del OS que decide qué proceso sigue en asignación de tiempo de CPU)

Nota: Usar un número muuuy negativo con un proceso muy intensivo en CPU puede causarte líos oprque te deja sin nada pa todo lo demás.

Por si acaso, en [esta pregunta de ServiceFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/228628/change-linux-process-priority) dicen básicamente lo mismo que esta respuesta y no me la estoy inventando

Comment: si esa parte la se lo que pasa es que estoy resolviendo un challenge de la pagina www.sandervanvugt.com, pero si utilizo renice -20 2022, no toma esa respuesta como correcta, por eso quería saber si conocen otra forma.

Comment: @rover suponer cosas que no están en la documentación es una mala forma de resolver el reto. Lo que busque o haga ese recurso externo está fuera de mi alcance :/ Si quieres, puedes poner el caso CONCRETO en tu pregunta (con eso quitas la premisa falsa e incluyes lo que intentaste y no te aceptan). Lo malo es que este sitio es público y van a ver tu pregunta si la buscan :P Y pues, si [la documentación de RedHat](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/manipulate-process-priority) dice esto...